# Why am I getting an Unknown property error?

Tags: visualforce

Why am I getting an Unknown property error in this code?

```
public class MywrapExample2 {
    List<wrapperAccountCheckbox> Lstwrp{set;get;}
    public MywrapExample2(){
        Lstwrp=new List<wrapperAccountCheckbox>();
        list<Application__c> appList=new List<Application__c>([select id,Lastname__c,firstname__c,Loan_type__c,Lead_score__c from Application__c]);
        for(Application__C appl:appList){
            Lstwrp.add(new wrapperAccountCheckbox(appl));
        }
    }
    //------wraper class-----------------------------------//
    public class wrapperAccountCheckbox{
        public boolean checkbox{get;set;}
        public String SLNo{get;set;}
        public Application__c app{set;get;}




public wrapperAccountCheckbox(Application__C appl){
        this.app=appl;
        this.checkbox=false;
    }

    }       
}
```

This is my VF page.

```
<apex:page controller="MywrapExample2" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Lstwrp}" var="w">
            <apex:column headerValue="select">
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!w.checkbox}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!w.app.lastname__C}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!w.app.firsname__C}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!w.app.Loan_type__C}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!w.app.lead_score__C}"/>
        </apex:pageblockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Maybe because the scope of the property is not public. Where are you generating that error?

Comment: are you using this in Javascript? I cannot see any annotations, but perhaps you removed them for clarity - if you are, Javascript is case sensitive and lstwrp is different to Lstwrp

Answer (score 2):

@Eric is right, the default scope of any variable in `Apex` is `private`. From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm):

**Private**

> This is the default, and means that the method or variable is accessible only within the Apex class in which it is defined. If you do not specify an access modifier, the method or variable is private.

You should add `public` in the variable declaration like this:

```
public List<wrapperAccountCheckbox> Lstwrp{set;get;}
```

Comment: Yup. @Eric is right.

Answer (score 0):

@ Rohit Mourya

in your code this  "List Lstwrp{set;get;} "  Lstwrp variable is private so you are not able to access that in another class or page.

just simply do it public List Lstwrp{set;get;} and your code will work.

Private class has their scope in within the same class and by default if we don't specify any access-specifier then it will be private by default.

Comment: hey, I haven't posted that question

Comment: sorry?? this is your question , because of that variable is private that's y you are getting error.

Comment: hehehehe, my bad